# IE8 freezes my animated GIF when running a JS scrolling gallery. Please help

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, gif, animated-gif

Thanks in advance for any help.
I'm currently using a nice animated GIF that i designed as the header logo for my site.  This was working until I put in a vertical scrolling gallery.
When the gallery starts to scroll (2 seconds after the page loads) the GIF freezes and doesnt continue until the gallery is paused.  The gallery works on a setInterval function and moves the images in the scroller a fraction each interval.
I've read that this is a documented problem with IE8 and has been fixed for IE9 (which works fine - and yes, I have tested it in IE9, unfortunately it has shaken my foundation of hating IE as it works quite nicely).
Anyway, has anyone got any ideas for a work around to get the GIF to animate at the same time as the gallery in IE8?  I've tried an Iframe and preloading the image.  However, if you want to suggest those ideas it would be good to see if i tried to do them correctly.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This would be tough to do since JavaScript is singlethreaded. The Gif animation consumes that single thread. So you cannot render a page and animate a gif at the same time.

Comment: No; I believe that isn't the issue.